# Can't open video picturebox using Opencv library

Tags: c#, opencv, picturebox

I can't open video in picturebox My code is:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.FileName = "*.*";
        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {


            isAnyText = false;
         //   string text = open.FileName;
          //  MessageBox.Show("resimin yolu :" + text);
          ///  CvVideoWriter video = new CvVideoWriter();
      //  videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHan
            CvCapture capture = new CvCapture(open.FileName);

            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(capture);



          //  pictureBox1.Image = capture;// new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        //pictureBox1.Capture = new Bitmap(open.FileName);

        //    pictureBox1.Image.
            string plaka = ft.GetImageText(open.FileName);
          var img = pictureBox1.Image;

        }
        foreach (var s in ft.textList)
            listBox1.Items.Add(s);

    }
```

I have a problem here

```
 pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(capture);
```

At the same time I try this:

```
pictureBox1.Capture = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
```

and I try lots of things but I cant do it
Any advance?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Shouldn't you use [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) or something for C# coding?

Comment: my error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Parametre is not true". and this code sentences : pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(capture);

Comment: Well that's because you are trying to create a [`Bitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) with a `CvCapture`...

Comment: Hmm Ok How  shuld I write for picturebox için

Comment: You might get a hint from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863918/opencv-how-to-display-webcam-capture-in-windows-form-application)

Comment: Thank you so much Now I have no error but video don't play I see only black screen

Comment: I cannot guess what you expect your program to do, but seems to me you are only displaying a single frame for each button click and not a video as you might be thinking.